# Cast hash result to int

Tags: azure-databricks, databricks-sql

How to cast the result of MD5 hashing to integer in Azure Databricks SQL?

```
SELECT MD5('text')
```

I tried CAST to int but it returns null:

```
SELECT CAST(MD5('text') as INT)
```

Comment: MD5 returns a 16-byte (binary) or 32-character (string) result .  That will not fit into a 4- or 8-byte integer.  The Databricks version returns a string - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/sql/language-manual/functions/md5

Comment: @DaveS, BIGINT would be possible?

Comment: "BIGINT Represents 8-byte signed integer numbers." and you need 16-byye  - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/sql/language-manual/sql-ref-datatypes

Comment: Any other hash algorithm that fits into INT?

Comment: MD5 is already weak, but yes hash tables have been written with smaller hash sizes.  What is your use case for the hash?

Comment: I need it for checksum, I just need to convert a string to integer for easier comparation in large tables in a BI project. @DaveS

Comment: You could use CRC-32 which is 4 bytes.  Note that the smaller the hash size the less it can distinguish between different inputs.  I have no idea how suitable it is for your use case

Comment: I need a hashing algorithm that has a native correspondent in both T-SQL and "Databricks SQL". CRC32 doesn't exist natively in T-SQL... @DaveS

Answer (score 0):

My Understanding is to convert the  **MD5**  Hash values to Int can be done with the  **CRC32.**
Need to cast the MD5 hash value with the  **CRC32**.

For example I have created a table with below schema. in azure Databricks

```
%sql
-- Create the table
CREATE  TABLE Hash2int02 (
id  INT,
name STRING,
hash_value STRING
);
```

[image]
Using the Update statemet the hash_value column with CRC32 converted values.

```
%sql
UPDATE Hash2int02
SET hash_value =  CRC32(hash_value);
```

[image]
Hash Value are now converted to Integer datatype.
[image]